# How to revert guake to old tab names

Tags: linux, terminal

How to revert guake to old tab names ("Terminal1") 
guake now renames tabs for every "cd" command change. and renames it to the current working directory. And this takes more space

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution.

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/guake/general/use_vte_titles --type boolean false
```

this will rename the tabs to "Terminal" but not giving every tab a name